# Writing better regex expression for not using lazy repeat quantifier

Tags: regex, reluctant-quantifiers

I have a regular expression:

```
(<select([^>]*>))(.*?)(</select\s*>)
```

Since it uses lazy repeat quantifier, for longer strings(having options more than 500) it backtracks for more than 100,000 times and fails.
Please help me to find a better regular expression which doesn't use lazy repeat quantifier

Comment: You can use possesive quantifiers. You can provide sample long input which is making your regex execution slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!/select>)[^<]*)*</select>
```

...or in human-readable form:

```
<select[^>]*>    # start tag
[^<]*            # anything except opening bracket
(?:              # if you find an open bracket
  <(?!/select>)  #   match it if it's not part of end tag
  [^<]*          #   consume any more non-brackets
)*               # repeat as needed
</select>        # end tag
```

This is an example of the "unrolled loop" technique Friedl develops in his book, [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/regex3/index.html).  I did a quick test in RegexBuddy using a pattern based on reluctant quantifiers:

```
(?s)<select[^>]*>.*?</select>
```

...and it took about 6,000 steps to find a match.  The *unrolled-loop* pattern took only 500 steps.  And when I removed the closing bracket from the end tag (`</select`), making a match impossible, it required only 800 steps to report failure.

If your regex flavor supports possessive quantifiers, go ahead and use them, too:

```
<select[^>]*+>[^<]*+(?:<(?!/select>)[^<]*+)*+</select>
```

It takes about the same number of steps to achieve a match, but it can use a lot less memory in the process.  And if no match is possible, it fails even more quickly; in my tests it took about 500 steps, the same number it took to find a match.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately this wont work, see the answer by Alan Moore for a correct example!**

```
(<select([^>]*>))(.*+)(</select\s*>)
```

From the perl regexp manpage:

> By default, when a quantified subpattern does not allow the rest of the
>          overall pattern to match, Perl will backtrack. However, this behaviour
>          is sometimes undesirable. Thus Perl provides the "possessive"
>          quantifier form as well.

```
       *+     Match 0 or more times and give nothing back
       ++     Match 1 or more times and give nothing back
       ?+     Match 0 or 1 time and give nothing back
       {n}+   Match exactly n times and give nothing back (redundant)
       {n,}+  Match at least n times and give nothing back
       {n,m}+ Match at least n but not more than m times and give nothing back
```

> For instance,

```
      'aaaa' =~ /a++a/
```

> will never match, as the "a++" will gobble up all the "a"'s in the
>          string and won't leave any for the remaining part of the pattern. This
>          feature can be extremely useful to give perl hints about where it
>          shouldn't backtrack. For instance, the typical "match a double-quoted
>          string" problem can be most efficiently performed when written as:

```
      /"(?:[^"\\]++|\\.)*+"/
```

Comment: Possessive quantifiers are a godsend, but they have to be used with much greater care than the other kinds.  Simply replacing the `?` with `+`, as you did, will almost never work.  Assuming the match is being done in dot-matches-all mode, the `(.*+)` in your regex will simply consume the entire rest of the input and not give anything back.

Comment: Not sure if this is such a good idea - he probably was using the lazy quantifier for a reason, namely to avoid matching over several `<select>` tags at once.

Comment: Possessive quantifier will fail in this case.(.*+) will match the complete string and it will always fail