# Unable to get rid of trailing characters when trying to fetch substring within a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to fetch 'domain' from 'http://domain.com/some-more-path' using regex:

`/(.*)(http|https):\/\/(.*)(\/)(.*)/ and then $3`

My issue is instead of 'domain' I get 'domain/some-more-path'. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
/(.*)(http|https):\/\/(.*)(\/)(.*)/
```

to

```
/(.*)(http|https):\/\/(.*?)(\/)(.*)/
```

The problem is the `.*` part. `*` is a greedy quantifier and will consume as much characters as possible. If you put a `?` behind the `*` you switch the behaviour of the qualifier to non-greedy (i.e. it consumes only as much characters as needed).

Comment: Reluctant quantifiers shouldn't be overused when not necessary. It causes much unnecessary backtracking in your case.

Comment: Was this answer correct? It seems to have been accepted but not upvoted... which wonders me why it has been accepted at all.

Comment: Was this question worth answering? Why wasn't it upvoted? In my opinion your answer is correct, though not optimal.

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html?page=3) for info on optimizing regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way:

```
/([^:]*):\/\/([^\/]*)(.*)/
```

Now $2 should be just a domain.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot javascript has got no possessive quantifiers (++, ?+, *+), like java do. Possessive quantifier would be even more suitable, hence there is no other option, thus no backtracking is necessary at all. Without it regex is just as optimal for a case there is a match, but much slower in case it should fail. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077135/writing-better-regex-expression-for-not-using-lazy-repeat-quantifier) for similar issue.